# Complex clustering of RNA-seq data

Tags: r, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

Even though I'm working with RNA-seq data, my question is more of a statistics and machine learning nature.

So, what I have is expression data from wild types (controls) and mutants over four different conditions, where a condition is a combination of two cell types and time points. Basically, my expression matrix looks like this:

```
     time1_loc1_control  time1_loc1_mutant  time1_loc2_control  time1_loc2_mutant ...
gene1    
gene2
...
```

Expression values are initially in counts-per-million, but I have tried using different transformations before clustering attempts.

What I am trying to achieve is to cluster the genes based on the direction of the change between mutant and control (upregulated or downregulated) and absolute values of expression.

So far I was able to roughly group the genes based solely on the direction of the change, but I would also need to retain the information of absolute expression values. Are there any methods that could help me with this?

One other idea was to split the dataset by conditions (as conditions are independent) and cluster the genes separately. This would mean each gene would be clustered four times. Is there any way to determine which genes are being clustered together?

Thank you for any input on this. I realize it's a bit vague but I am not extremely experienced with this.

Kind regards,
Z

Comment: Have you looked into biclustering?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biclustering

Comment: This is not about programming, but about statistics and therefore probably off-topic here. You may want to migrate your question to biostars, stats, or similar sites.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I apologize for the off-topic post and will look at the sites mentioned.

I'm not sure that biclustering would be useful here. From my understanding, it is used to cluster both rows and columns of the matrix, which is not something I need. Ideally I would need something to preform clustering based on distance of the genes with respect to direction of the change between control and mutant.